# SSIS Transfer few tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis

I would like to have a stored procedure that return 3 results. these results are all the data i have about a person. the orders he made, his favorite products and his personal details. I would like to take these 3 results and save them in 3 different tables in the destination database. Is it possible to do it, or I have to do one by one?
I was thinking of maybe using a recordset destination, but i don't know how to read from each table in the recordset into a different table in the destination database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a script task to add a layer between your SP, and your tables.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32151/How-to-Use-a-Multi-Result-Set-Stored-Procedure-in

If the tables are on the same DB as your SP, you might just want to write directly to to tables.